# (SpringBoot, JPA, Mysql) Error configuring logic to store user

Tags: jpa, model-view-controller

Used : Mysql, JPA, SpringBoot

The following is the information I requested in Json format.

```
{
    "id" : "abc@naver.com",
    "password" : "abc1234",
    "name" : "hi",
    "phoneNumber" : "01012341234",
    "ssn" : "0000000000000",
    "cityName" : "seoul",
    "townName" : "shinjeongdong",
    "streetName" : "teheranro-22",
    "zipCode" : "55950",
    "dateils" : "5 floor"
}
```

Failed to configure logic to receive values through 'UserInfoDto' using PostMapping and store values in the 'Users' table.
I don't know what's wrong...

'Users' Entity

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;


import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.UserInfoDto;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ssn","phone_number"})})
public class Users {

    @Column(name = "id", length = 40, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", length = 12, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name =  "ssn", length = 13, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ssn;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "point")
    private Long point;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postedUser")
    private List<PostInfo> uploadedPost = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<PointHistory> pointHistories = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    private Dates dates;

    public Users(UserInfoDto userInfoDto){
        this.setId(userInfoDto.getId());
        this.setPassword(userInfoDto.getPassword());
        this.setPhoneNumber(userInfoDto.getPhoneNumber());
        this.setSsn(userInfoDto.getSsn());
        this.setPoint(0L);

        Address address = new Address(
                userInfoDto.getCityName(),
                userInfoDto.getTownName(),
                userInfoDto.getStreetName(),
                userInfoDto.getZipCode(),
                userInfoDto.getDetailsCode()
        );

        this.setAddress(address);

        List<PostInfo> postInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PointHistory> pointHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.setUploadedPost(postInfoList);
        this.setPointHistories(pointHistoryList);

        Dates dates = new Dates(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());

        this.setDates(dates);
    }
}
```

It's Entity 'Address', an embedded entity in 'Users'.

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    @Column(name = "city_name", nullable = false) //도시명
    private String cityName;

    @Column(name = "town_name", length = 20) //동명
    private String townName;

    @Column(name = "street_name", length = 20, nullable = false) //도로명
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "zip_code", length = 20) // 우편번호
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "details",length = 20) //상세주소
    private String detailsCode;

    protected Address() {
    }

}
```

This is the Dto to use instead of the 'Users' entity.

```
package My_Project.integration.entity.Dto;

import My_Project.integration.entity.PointHistory;
import My_Project.integration.entity.PostInfo;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
public class UserInfoDto {

    private String id;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String ssn;

    private String cityName;
    private String townName;
    private String streetName;
    private String zipCode;
    private String detailsCode;

    private Long point;

    public UserInfoDto(String id, String password, String name, String phoneNumber, String ssn, String cityName, String townName, String streetName, String zipCode, String detailsCode, Long point) {
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.ssn = ssn;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.townName = townName;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.detailsCode = detailsCode;
        this.point = point;
    }

    public UserInfoDto() {
    }
}
```

```
package My_Project.integration.controller;

import My_Project.integration.entity.*;
import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.UserInfoDto;
import My_Project.integration.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SignupPageController {

    @Autowired private UserService userService;
    @PostMapping("/signup_execute")
    public String signUp(UserInfoDto userInfoDto) {
        try {
            Users users = new Users(userInfoDto);
            userService.addUsers(users);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/errorpage";
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

```
package My_Project.integration.service;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Users;
import My_Project.integration.repository.UsersRepository;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.Throw;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Users addUsers(Users users) throws Exception{
        if (!usersRepository.duplicateCheck(users)) {
            throw new Exception("중복된 값이 검출되었습니다.");
        } else {
            usersRepository.save(users);
            System.out.println("Users 엔티티를 저장하였습니다.");
            return users;
        }
    }


}
```

```
package My_Project.integration.repository.UserCustom.Impl;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Users;
import My_Project.integration.repository.UserCustom.UserCustomRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.Throw;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.swing.text.html.Option;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserCustomRepositoryImpl implements UserCustomRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public boolean duplicateCheck(Users users) {
        Query query1 = em.createQuery("select u from Users u where u.id = :name",Users.class)
                        .setParameter("name",users.getId());
        List resultList1 = query1.getResultList();
        if(!resultList1.isEmpty()) return false;

        Query query2 = em.createQuery("select u from Users u where u.phoneNumber= :name",Users.class)
                .setParameter("name",users.getPhoneNumber());
        List resultList2 = query2.getResultList();
        if(!resultList2.isEmpty()) return false;

        Query query3 = em.createQuery("select u from Users u where u.ssn = :name",Users.class)
                .setParameter("name",users.getSsn());
        List resultList3 = query3.getResultList();
        if(!resultList3.isEmpty()) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

It's error content....

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): My_Project.integration.entity.Users; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): My_Project.integration.entity.Users
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy109.save(Unknown Source)
    at My_Project.integration.service.UserService.addUsers(UserService.java:26)
    at My_Project.integration.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$636d190f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at My_Project.integration.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7615f959.addUsers(<generated>)
    at My_Project.integration.controller.SignupPageController.signUp(SignupPageController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): My_Project.integration.entity.Users
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy105.persist(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy105.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 71 more
```

Successful data storage was expected, but it was not.

Comment: Don't you need to specify that the parameter `userInfoDto` in `String signUp(UserInfoDto userInfoDto)` must be taken from the request body ? with `@RequestBody` ?

Comment: That's what I missed. But it's the same error again ;D

Comment: Does it mean that when you step in `public String signUp(UserInfoDto userInfoDto)`, the `userDtoInfo` is completly empty ?

Comment: Yes! And I tried to print out of the controller that uses UserInfoDto as a parameter. But it didn't work. ;d

Comment: Do you use a tool like Postman to send the request ?

Comment: You should set a breakpoint in the `UserDtoInfo` default constructor and in the `id` setter to check when (or if) it is called.

Comment: OMG I Found it In 'UserInfoDto', there was a name field, but in 'Users', there was no name field.